# call to undefined function exif_read_data() - but cannot access php.ini file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I know this question is asked several times. I have the same issue with uploading image from iPhone. That is the image is rotating on upload. I have tried to use

> exif_read_data()

but I got the error `call to undefined function exif_read_data()` and I have find solution here that to change the php.ini file from

```
1   extension=php_mbstring.dll

2   extension=php_exif.dll
```

to

```
1   extension=php_exif.dll

2   extension=php_mbstring.dll`
```

but I am not able to access the php.ini file . Is there any other way to set this withou accessing the php.ini file(through htaccess or like that)???

**Update**
Is there any way to solve this issue without using

> exif_read_data()

or any other additional libraries???

Comment: If you can't access php.ini (and restart PHP/server) then you can't enable this extension.

Comment: but my public_html folder contain no files with name php.ini I have contacted them for getting this file and waiting for their reply. Any other thing that I can do here????

Comment: No, this sounds like something your host will need to resolve.

Comment: Exif must be after mbstring as exif depends upon mbstring! But if they have it configured in the wrong order you should be able to get it changed. Normally extensions get put in php.ini in alphabetic order, this one should stick out like a sore thumb

Comment: ok thanks..................

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can try this one

```
if(extension_loaded("exif"))
    $exif_data = exif_read_data('sample.jpg','EXIF',true);
else 
    $exif_data = false;
```